# Fast algorithm for computing minimal closure of a set of sets under intersection?

Tags: algorithms, sets, algorithm-design

A step of an algorithm I’ve designed requires computing the minimal closure under intersection of a set of sets of arbitrary size. By the "minimal closure (of a set $S$) under intersection", I mean:

Given a set $S$ containing sets $s_1, \cdots , s_k$, the smallest set $′$ such that $S\subseteq S'$ and $x\cap y \in S'$ for any two sets $x, y \in S'$.

While I can come up with a pretty straightforward naive approach (loop over the sets and store all the intersections in a new set, then update the set as the union of previous step’s set and the new set, and repeat this process until the new and old set are the same), I am looking for a faster method, but haven’t been able to find any papers working on a similar problem. Does anybody know if there are faster existing algorithms to solve this problem before I attempt to potentially reinvent the — or a worse version of — the wheel? Or if not exact solutions, maybe fast approximation algorithms on other data structures (e.g. sets of strings) that translate to this problem setup?

Comment: The result will literally be the set $S'$ containing all sets $s'$ of the form $s'=\bigcap s\in A$ for some $A\subseteq S'$. Since the output can be incredibely large, (up to an exponantial size in the input) - there is no "fast" algorithm for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no polynomial-time algorithm.  The output can potentially be exponentially large, so any algorithm will have inputs on which it must take exponential time.  For instance, if $s_i=\{1,2,\cdots, k\}\setminus\{i\}$, then $S'$ contains $2^k$ elements, so any algorithm must take $\Omega(2^k)$ time (it takes that much time even just to output $S'$, let alone to calculate it).

One simple approach is a workload algorithm, where you incrementally generate new sets that are in the closure.  In particular:

- Set $W := S$.  (The worklist is initialized to $S$.)
- Set $S' := S$.
- While $W \ne \emptyset$:

  - Pop an element from $W$, call it $s$.
  - Let $T := \{s \cap s' \mid s' \in S', s \cap s' \notin S'\}$.
  - Set $W := W \cup T$ and $S' := S' \cup T$.

Comment: @JohnL., oh, right!  Thank you.  Fixed.

Comment: Here is a simpler and faster algorithm. Computes $C_i$, the minimal closure of $\{s_1, s_2,\cdots, s_i\}$ for $i=0,1,2,\cdots,k$. $C_0=\emptyset$. $C_{i+1}=C_i\cup\{s\cap s_{i+1}\mid s\in C_i\}$. Return $C_k$. This algorithm is optimal in the sense that in the worst case, each $s\cap s_{i+1}$ will always be a new set. (I do not want to write another answer).

Comment: @JohnL., Thank you for the simpler algorithm!  In my algorithm, if $s=s'$, then $s \cap s' \in S'$, and nothing is added to $W$ -- so I don't understand why you say $W$ will never become empty.

Comment: Changing a collection such as a set or a list while looping over it is apparently ambiguous.

Comment: @JohnL., "pop" means pick a single element of $W$ (any one is fine) and remove it.  It doesn't mean looping over it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments about modifying a collection while iterating over it.  Is the revised pseudocode any better?

Comment: My algorithm should have the following. Compute $\mathcal C_i$ for $i=\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$. $\mathcal C_1:=\{s_1\}$. $\mathcal C_{i+1}:=\mathcal C_i\cup\{s_{i+1}\}\cup\{c\cap s_{i+1}\mid c\in \mathcal C_i\}$). Return $C_k$.

Comment: For your algorithm, "set $W := W \cup T$" can be skipped completely. (Then your algorithm becomes almost the same as my algorithm.)

Comment: "My algorithm should have the following" should have been "My algorithm should have been the following".